# Just download content of remote branch , not the repository

Tags: git, git-checkout

Do we have anyway to just download content of a branch , and not the repository. I need a branch to do build on a server, So I am interested only in just my files not any repository stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `--single-branch` modifier for the git clone. Supposing a branch called `my_branch`

`$ git clone --single-branch --branch my_branch`

This will download all history for the branch. Using `--depth` modifier, you can get only the most recent revisions:

`$ git clone --depth 1 --single-branch --branch my_branch`

Comment: I need just content , no repository stuff. Problem is I have very limited memory on my system. I tried earlier your suggestion already and its throwing OUT OF MEMORY exception.